# When I convert a PyTorch model to onnx, I get many files, why?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

when I convert a torch model to onnx, I get many files like you can see in the images below:

[image]

[image]

No errors were reported during conversion. And my code is:

```
model_path = "./saved_models/emotion_model_temp/"
config = BertConfig.from_json_file(model_path)  # 加载bert模型配置信息
config.num_labels=3

device = 'cuda'
input_ids_np = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros([1, 128], dtype=np.int64))
token_type_ids_np = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros([1, 128], dtype=np.int64))
attention_mask_np = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros([1, 128], dtype=np.int64))
input_ids_tf = input_ids_np.type(torch.int64).to(device)
token_type_ids_tf = token_type_ids_np.type(torch.int64).to(device)
attention_mask_tf = attention_mask_np.type(torch.int64).to(device)
feature_wav = torch.from_numpy(np.array(np.zeros((1,313, 128, 1))))
feature_wav_tf = feature_wav.type(torch.float32).to(device)

model = EmotionModel.from_pretrained(model_path, config=config).to("cuda")
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(model_path, "pytorch_model.bin"),map_location="cuda"))
print("####  加载模型完成")
model.eval()

onnx_name = "./temp/temp.onnx"
torch.onnx.export(model,  # model being run
                  (input_ids_tf,token_type_ids_tf,attention_mask_tf,feature_wav_tf),  # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                  onnx_name,  # where to save the model
                  opset_version=11,  # the ONNX version to export the model to
                  input_names=['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'feature_wav'],
                  output_names=['logits'],
                  dynamic_axes={"input_ids": {0: "batch_size"},  # 批处理变量
                                "token_type_ids": {0: "batch_size"},
                                "attention_mask": {0: "batch_size"},
                                "feature_wav": {0: "batch_size"},}
                  )
```

Does anyone know what happened to my onnx conversion？

Answer (score 0):

I get it. Because onnx file is bigger than 2G.
But another question , if onnx model larger than 2G, Then how to do ?